# What does the symbol ">" stand for

Tags: css

I am aware of css id and class but I have never seen this

`.forumbg-table > .inner {
    margin: 0 -1px;
}`

Could you please let me know what does it stands for?

Comment: Which part of it is unclear? There's several things here. Do you mean the `>`?

Comment: If you mean `A > B`, this is the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

Comment: `Another type of css`....where is that in your question fella.....!!????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the direct descendant selector. It selects immediate children of the first selector.

Here is the syntax:

```
parentSelector > immediateChildSelector
{
  //Properties here
}
```

ex.

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <label class='lbl1'>Label</label>
 </div>

<label class='lbl1'>Label 2</label>

#parentDiv > .lbl1
{
  color: blue;
}
```

In the example above the second label wont get the color of blue because it's not a direct child of the parentDiv element.

Here is a live sample: http://jsbin.com/iWuSUde/1/edit

Here is a reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors

Answer (score 1):

Selects all `inner` class elements where the parent is a  `.forumbg-table` class element